# "Debating" question mark/badge

Tags: feature-request, questions, opinion-based

How about marking hot questions like [The art of programming: Java vs C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610199/the-art-of-programming-java-vs-c-sharp) as "debating" questions? A debating question - a question which has several alternative applicable answers each of which having it's own pros and cons.

If question is marked as a debating then answers to this question can be presented in a slightly different way, clearly showing the alternative answers/views.

I think in some cases such questions can be automatically detected considering how users are voting. E.g. users which support a certain answer would vote against another answers.

**UPDATE**

Thank you everyone for pointing out that such questions don't fit the format of Stack Overflow or Stack Exchange.
Even if the majority of such questions are closed sooner or later, I suggest they could have been automatically marked with the "debating"-like mark/badge. The "debating"-marked questions could be more easily detected and closed by the admins/sineor members.

Comment: See [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/310998) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Or just use [our](https://www.quora.com/Is-C-better-than-Java?share=1) [evil](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-a-better-Language-c-or-java?share=1) [twin](https://www.quora.com/Currently-which-one-is-best-C-Java-or-C++?share=1) (the last one has 49 answer, although more specific than this example).

Comment: I updated my answer, I'm curious about how you plan to automatically detect debating questions.

Comment: You want the asker to use a particular tag so that their questions can be closed more quickly? Could work :-)

Answer (score 9):

We don't want debating questions, and the close reason of that question explains why:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, visit the help center for guidance.

Also see [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions):

> These are the categories of questions that may be closed by the
>   community:
>
> - [...]
> - primarily opinion-based - [discussions focused on diverse opinions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) are great, but they
>     just don't fit our format well.
>
>   > Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost
>   >     entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or
>   >     specific expertise.

Answer (score 8):

Debating questions don't belong on Stack Overflow or any Stack Exchange site. They're almost instantaneously closed as ***primarily opinion-based***.

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

Subjective questions are only allowed under [very strict rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun
>
> For more detail, read about our [guidelines for great subjective questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and blog post about how [real questions have answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

---

Regarding your update: do you have any proposal for such a detection algorithm? 10k users already have access to [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), where they can see which posts have a large amount of comments, or are edited many times. It could be worthwhile to have a list of 'most controversial' posts there as well - controversial meaning having a lot of up- *and* downvotes.

Comment: Yes, I will update with an algorithm once I finish it