# Is there a community (stack*) to debate about some matter?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, proposed-changes, community-moderation, forums

My question is similar to [that one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337852/debating-question-mark-badge) but in this case, I´m asking for a different web/community where one can debate/rebate about any theme of a matter (preferably classifiable) with the same or similar writing interface (LaTex is compulsory) and model of moderation (except one thing ... suggestion and comments might be privacy to author and zero offensive).

For example, my teacher says that NP class contains only P and NP-complete problems, but I think he is wrong. We decided to open the debate publicly where anyone can throw its arguments but not only voting the question.

I think sometimes we learn things because we have to pass an exam, not understanding what logic is behind, and we never discuss that even when logic is inexistent. I think now we have a great opportunity to break this "status quo" of worshipping the word of the lord.

It can be very useful as a background for students, teachers, professors or researchers ... and the knowledge/science will grow collectively.

I have read the question [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe) and it is not exactly with the same aim. I'm talking about a discussion with high-level knowledge on the matter (not for beginners or thugs). I think that for begginers SE works fine as it is, I´m talking about discusing the "status of the art" because things changes every day, and wht our "professors" had known as correct today may be not exactly the most accurate answer.

Comment: You're looking for a forum, and if there is one that stack exchange isn't, it's a forum (except for the chat rooms)

Comment: But why not? It seems to be interesting, isn't?

Comment: There are other venues for this, and so why should SO reproduce those? Also, the formula here is to have a decent collection of Q/A with a high signal to noise ratio, meaning, keep chat to a minimum and instead provide the meat

Comment: It can be decent discussions aswell. Anyway, where is a site like this? (Latex is compulsory)

Comment: Please see [Are Stack Exchange sites forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computer Science SE ( https://cs.stackexchange.com ) is your friend.

Although open-ended, forum-like questions are generally unwelcomed on the SE site network. It is because the sites try to become a concentrated information resource, i.e. clear question, clear answer, no chit-chat.

But this question has a clear and objective answer, thus such a discussion is not even needed.

Although it can happen in comments, or in the [chatrooms belonging to the CS SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thx @peterh ... I think there is an excessive "zeal" on this matter and sadly there is no other site with LaTex incorporated in Q&A interface. Why not make an spin-off of SE with the same interface for discussing those not fully clear questions? Why people downvote my question if it is a fair question and not a discussion thread?

Comment: @Ibai Because the SE does not want it. An alternative site should be created, but it would not have enough visitors, because all of them are now already on the SE. https://codidact.org is the latest try to spin off. Btw, also wikipedia is a pile of crap: not only that it is painfully single-sided in all argumentable questions, did you ever try to *understand* anything there? There is also a far worser opinion terror of an inbreed circle, as on the SO. But, https://citizendium.org, a wikipedia spinoff, died due to the social inertia. No one visitied it.

Comment: @Ibai If you unaccept my answer, then I will be able to delete it. If your question has no more answers, you will be able to delete it. So you won't end up with a -20 question in your profile. If your MSO profile is important for you (I long stopped it), this is the only way to ever delete your question. It is a "funny" way of the community, to deter new users from participating, that they create undeletable, deeply downvoted questions in their profile. If anybody posts yet another answer, even this option closes.